# switching play/pause button images

Tags: javascript, image, video

I currently have HTML, with a video and a div to add a play/pause button, and javascript to remove the control, and to toggle between play/pause. My javascript function works perfectly to toggle between the text Play and Pause, however I cannot figure out how to switch the image. 
Thanks for help in advance, my current code is included below

```
function playpause() {
if (video.paused || video.ended) {
    if (video.ended) video.currentTime=0;
    ppbutton.title="pause";
    ppbutton.innerHTML="PAUSE"
    video.play()
}
else {
    ppbutton.title="play";
    ppbutton.innerHTML="PLAY"
    video.pause()
}
```

}

```
<div id="controls">
    <div id="playpause" title="play" onClick="playpause()"><img src="media/playbutton.png"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    video.controls = false;

    var ppbutton = document.getElementById("playpause");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**could** use the same method as you were setting the text :

```
ppbutton.innerHTML='<img src="media/stopbutton.png"/>';
```

**or** give the image an `id` also and go more directly :

```
<img src="media/stopbutton.png" id="ppImage"/>
```

__

```
document.getElementById('ppImage').src='media/stopbutton.png';
```

---

**or let CSS do it**

```
#playpause { 
     display:block; 
     height:40px; width:150px; /* dimensions of the image */
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     cursor:pointer;
}

#playpause.play { 
    background-image:url("media/stopbutton.png");
}

#playpause.pause { 
    background-image:url("media/pause.png");
}

#playpause.stop { 
    background-image:url("media/stop.png");
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="playpause" title="play" onClick="playpause()"></div>
```

***JS line to add class***

```
document.getElementById('playpause').className='pause';
```

---

If going down the CSS route, a **sprite** might be worth a look or even better maybe using asci codes , eg.

```
document.getElementById('playpause').innerHTML='&#9658'; /* asci for 'play' */
```

---

**[Font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)** is worth a look too